# Disable Reload For nginx Service

Tags: systemd, reboot, nginx

There is a bug in Ubuntu 20.04 with nginx due to core libperl which causes a segfault when doing two consecutive reloads of the service (`systemctl reload nginx`).

Here is the bug: [1897561 - libperl.so.5.30.0 causes nginx to segfault](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/+bug/1897561?comments=all)

As this bug has been around for ages, I have a feeling it won't be fixed for some time so I'm trying to find a patch to prevent `reload nginx` from getting run by either mapping it to `restart` or disabling it altogether.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it already has been fixed ([See ticket 1831](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1831); that one is related to bug 1897561 but later and has better information). Problem was a bug in [perl version 5.30](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17154) (5.28 did not have this) and is fixed in perl version 5.30.2 and higher.

You do need 22.04 for that though and I doubt it is not easy nor a good idea to upgrade perl on 20.04. If you can do that it would be an option to fix it.

If you do not use perl applications you can also do this:

```
rm -f /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

and `service nginx reload` will no longer crash.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is still a bit too fresh for some other dependencies in our infrastructure. For nginx, we are using ModSecurity which I think uses perl. In light of other hard stops I've gotten with Ubuntu, I've decided to make the jump to Debian for all my environments. Just have to get the ZFS Root working; which is a dream in Ubuntu desktop :-/